# ThreeFiber Drei PivotControls, get position after onDragEnd

Tags: react-three-fiber, react-three-drei

I'm trying to get the updated position of a mesh after moving it with the Drei Pivot Controls, but digging into the object it says the position is [0,0,0].  How can I console.log the position after dragging a mesh?

```
  const meshRef = useRef();
  const handleDragEnd = () => {
    const model = meshRef.current
    debugger
  };
  
  return (
    <PivotControls anchor={[0, 0, 0]} onDragEnd ={handleDragEnd}>
        <primitive ref={meshRef} scale={scale} position={position} rotation={rotation} object={loadedModel.scene} />
    </PivotControls>
  )
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to grab it during the "onDrag" event and store it somewhere. I believe it's in global coordinates, so you might have to convert to local.

```
    onDrag={(l, dl, w, dw) => {
      // Extract the position and rotation
      const position = new THREE.Vector3()
      const rotation = new THREE.Quaternion()
      // I'm never sure whether to grab "l" or "w" here... sorry
      w.decompose(position, rotation, new Vector3())
      setPosition(position)
  }}
>
```